# is it possible to import ora scn values and not changed?

Tags: oracle

I have a table that it has rowdempendency enabled , and I want to export/import it to another schema having the same ora_scn not changed. but using the data pump export/import the ora scn is changing.
Is there a way a keep the ora scn not changed ? I tried the below:

```
drop table test_MD
/
Create table test_MD 
(id number(3) null, 
name varchar2(100) null)
rowdependencies
/
 insert into test_MD (id , name) values (1,'ONE')
/
commit
/
 select id,name,ORA_ROWSCN from TEST_MD
/
insert into test_MD (id , name) values (2,'TWO')
/
commit
/
 select id,name,ORA_ROWSCN from TEST_MD
 -- ORA_ROWSCN =230702466 230702475
/
expdp testschema/testschema@testsrvr tables=TEST_MD directory=scehmadir dumpfile=MD_DMP.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log
/
alter table TEST_MD rename to TEST_MD1
/
impdp testschema1/testschema1@testsrvr tables=TEST_MD directory=scehmadir dumpfile=MD_DMP.dmp logfile=impdpEMP_DEPT.log
/
select id,name,ORA_ROWSCN from TEST_MD1
/
ORA_ROWSCN = 230708371 230708371
```

My problem is here , i want the value to stay
-- ORA_ROWSCN =230702466 230702475

is that possible ? or is there an alternative way?

Comment: No. What are you doing that relies on you knowing the SCN?

Comment: hi @AlexPoole no i dont know the ora scn, here an example to show the difference number occuring. in my example i have billion of rows

Comment: No, you can't. Every DML (and many internal recursive actions) call the kcmgas function which moves SCN forward, not to mention the leaps forward it makes in distributed queries. There's no way to freeze it, copy it, etc.. as an SCN. The whole point is to internally serialize changes so that Oracle knows exactly what order changes happened in and when relative to other changes or queries. If you could manipulate it (and you can't), you'd completely mess up the database. You can of course store it as a user column, but then it ceases to have any special meaning.

Comment: Don't use ORA_ROWSCN for programming. It's for the database's internal use and is used by us only on rare occasion for management purposes (recovery, flashback, etc). If you need to track row age, add a user column to your table with a date or timestamp datatype and populate it via code or trigger. That's something you can rely on programmatically. SCN isn't.

Comment: @PaulW well I had a tough discussion with the management about this approach but they decided to go with it in all cases. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot export and import Oracle data and reliably preserve the ORA_ROWSCN values. In fact, you cannot even reliably preserve the ORA_ROWSCN values for your existing data, even if you do not change anything.

Carefully read the [lengthy description of the ORA_ROWSCN pseudofunction in the SQL Language Reference.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ORA_ROWSCN-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-8071AAB0-F656-4C93-B926-0BCE1439F121) The description starts with the simple phrase "the ORA_ROWSCN should not be considered to be an exact SCN", and then repeats itself multiple times because it is so tempting to use the ORA_ROWSCN like a precise value.

But the ORA_ROWSCN will never be precise and stable. It will seemingly randomly change for the same row, depending on precisely how you query for the row. Unfortunately, I cannot create a simple test case to verify this behavior. When the problem happened to me, it didn't happen often, and the manual does not fully document the behavior.

Abandon all hope. Even if you get a proof of concept that works today - maybe some physical copy mechanism like VM cloning, PDB cloning, or transportable tablespaces can create seemingly similar ORA_ROWSCN values - the values will never be reliably stable.

Comment: actually it did happen to me this behavoir where data is being changed randomly or its not behaved correctly. what i did is running a random select after a dml, it seems it refresh the ora scn. thanks for your info.